# Flex not matching both NUL \0 and <<EOF>>

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I have a flex file where I have rules for both NUL and <EOF>. I want my file to match both NULs and <EOF> when encountered in the input.

At the time, I think <EOF> takes precedence, and flex doesn't match NUL "\0" even if it is present in the input.

Any help to resolve this is appreciated!

Thanks!

```
"\0"    {printf("\n I saw null\n");}

<<EOF>>      {flex_shell_action (yyextra,SHELL_END_OF_FILE , yyscanner);
            if(yyextra->debug) printf("Reached end of input for Shell\n");fflush(stdout);
          yyterminate();}
```

My sample input-string is : "for date in\0 foo.txt \0/usr/local:"

Comment: How do you provide your **sample input-string** to your script? File? Redirection? Pipe?

Comment: If you are on UNIX/Linux you can pipe your input to `od -oc` or similar to check that it contains the desired codes.

Comment: Checking http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns, it says that ‘`\0`’ matches NUL, and that ‘`"[xyz]\"foo"`’ matches the literal string: ‘[xyz]"foo’, but it does not specify complete rules for interpreting within `""`. Have you tried ‘`\0`’ without `""`?

Comment: For better or worse, `yylex()` returns 0 on EOF.  Therefore, to recognize ASCII NUL `'\0'`, you will have to arrange to return some non-zero value for it.  An obvious value is 256, one larger than the largest 8-bit non-zero character code.  AFAICR, that is not reserved by `lex` or `yacc`.
What I don't immediately remember is whether GUN `flex` simply ignores all null bytes in its input.  I could believe that it does if the input is a string; it shouldn't but may do so if the input is a file.  (And this uncertainty is why this is a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: The patterns work for me with flex 2.5.35, exactly as written. The default action mentioned by Jonathan Leffler is suppressed by the presence of an `<<EOF>>` rule. Nulls are matched just fine. I think @DavidC.Rankin has the right idea: you have failed to get the nulls *into* the parser. You need to show a complete program - and a complete transcript of how you are attempting to run the program - if you want anyone to be able to help you.